# Phonegap xmlhttprequest doesn't return xml data

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmlhttprequest, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm building a hybrid app using phonegap. I'm designing the login page. I've been able to reach the webservice but not able to retrieve the details.

Following is my Script in loginpage for sending http request.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
            $.ajax({    
                url: "http://developer.meritmerge.com/mmapk/mmservice.asmx/MMLogin",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: { MailID:$("#username").val(),PWD:$("#password").val()},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("yes");
                },
                error: function(err)
                {
                    alert("Oops! Something went wrong!");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Following is the output I get when I run this on my browser directly using the url and passing username and password:

```
<UserDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://meritmerge.com/">
<UserID>357</UserID>
<IsAdmin>true</IsAdmin>
<ResponseCode>1</ResponseCode>
<SchoolID>20</SchoolID>
<RoleID>37</RoleID>
<ImageUrl>http://www.meritmerge.com/ClientsLogo/20.png</ImageUrl>
</UserDetails>
```

In my script, under succeess part when I give "alert("yes");" it alerts as yes, but when I try to retrieve the actual data i.e., UserID, RoleID, it shows blank data.

Is my dataType correct? It had same reaction when I used dataType as text.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not posted the main portion of your code, I mean the code using which you are retrieving the data in success callback

Comment: Solved it!

It was returning an object, had to just access the text() of it.

Comment: As mentioned, the response parsing was your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! It was returning an object, had to just access the text() of it.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
                $.ajax({    
                    url: "http://developer.meritmerge.com/mmapk/mmservice.asmx/MMLogin",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: { MailID:$("#username").val(),PWD:$("#password").val()},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $response = $(data).find( "ResponseCode" ).text();
                        if($response == 1)
                            {
                                localStorage["userid"] = $(data).find( "UserID" ).text();
                                localStorage["isadmin"] = $(data).find( "IsAdmin" ).text();
                                localStorage["schoolid"] = $(data).find( "SchoolID" ).text();
                                localStorage["schoolname"] = $(data).find( "SchoolName" ).text();
                                localStorage["username"] = $(data).find( "UserName" ).text();
                                localStorage["roleid"] = $(data).find( "RoleID" ).text();
                                localStorage["mailid"] = $(data).find( "MailID" ).text();
                                localStorage["imageurl"] = $(data).find( "ImageUrl" ).text();
                                localStorage["schoolid"] = $(data).find( "StudentID" ).text();
                                alert("Welcome, "+localStorage["schoolname"]);
                                window.location.href = "dashboard.html";
                            }
                        else if($response == -999)
                            {
                                alert("Incorrect Credentials!");
                                $('input[type="text"]#username').val('');
                                $('input[type="password"]#password').val('');
                                $('input[type="text"]#username').focus();
                            }
                    },
                    error: function(err)
                    {
                        alert("Oops! Something went wrong!");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the code I've been using to fetch the data!

But now it runs on the browser, but on android phone, it always goes to the err part and alerting "Oops! something is wrong!". I'm not sure what's going on!!!!

Comment: Do yo have enabled CORS for AJAX request and included whitelist plugin?